# What application displays disk details?

Tags: hard-drive, software-recommendation, ssd

Does anyone know a software like [Crystalmark](http://crystalmark.info/?lang=en) where can I see all the information about my disk?  Crystalmark, unfortunately, is only available for Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `gnome-disks`. (This is the `Disks` application in the Unity dash).

You can see all information on you hard drive, do benchmarks and see SMART attributs.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To manipulate you HDD and other devices, use GParted (I do not recommend you to use KDE Disk manager, it is said to be buggy):
Type on terminal :

`apt-get install gparted`

There you can use GParted from Settings->GParted.

To monitor and control SMART data on hard disks, use GSmartControl:

Type on terminal :

`apt-get install gsmartcontrol`

To monitor temperature of Hard Disk Drive, use PSensor:

`apt-get install psensor`

Extra: GraphicalDiskMap is a tool which allows you to visualize disk space:

`apt-get install gdmap`

Answer (score 0):

I am using gparted (on XFCE) if you have KDE you can use KDE Disk manager too.

The tool give you access to arrange / re-arrange your disk partition.

[gparted image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzmAi.jpg)

Hope I helped you, if not please answer...