# Can't boot Ubuntu 16.04 Grub/HD mount problem?

Tags: boot, grub2, grub-efi, ubuntu-drivers

Please help me, I have issues with Ubuntu all week.

When boot I get this message:

```
error: failure reading sector 0x2402a18 from `hd0'.
```

`alloc magic is broken at 0xca5a8560: ca4exae0
Aborted. Press any key to exit._`

This link is my boot script info: http://paste.ubuntu.com/24336967/

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The `failure reading sector` message suggests that your hard disk may be failing. You can check the disk's SMART data, as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38566/how-can-i-check-the-health-of-my-hard-drive) or [here,](https://askubuntu.com/questions/720587/what-application-displays-disk-details) to cite just a couple of references. Note, however, that SMART data can be difficult to interpret, and SMART doesn't always detect failing disks, so even if the results look OK, the disk could be failing.

If I'm right, the only solution is to buy a new disk and transfer as much of your data as you can to it. Although failing disks can sometimes remain usable for long periods by using various utilities to make the OS ignore the bad sectors, this is a risky proposition. Failing disks often continue to deteriorate, and in an unpredictable way -- you might lose no new sectors today, fifty more tomorrow, two more the day after that, a thousand more on the third day, none more for another two weeks, and then the disk will become completely unresponsive one day.

Another possibility is some other hardware failure, like a bad cable. This is a much less expensive fix, but if the disk is consistently failing to read a specific sector, a bad cable is an unlikely cause.